# Mockito To Verify ArrayList Size

Tags: android, mockito

My Adapter has getItemCount method in which ArrayList returns size of items. How to i verify it with Mockito as i don't have any view in that method?

```
static class SongAdapterPresenter implements SortedSongSelectionContract.SongAdapterContract.Presenter {
.....
....
 @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return songs != null ? songs.size() : 0;
        }
}
```

My Mockito Class code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Log.class)
public class SongAdapterPresenterTest {

    private SortedSongSelectionPresenter.SongAdapterPresenter songAdapterPresenter;

    @Mock
    private SortedSongSelectionContract.SongAdapterContract.Adapter adapter;

    @Mock
    private SortedSongSelectionContract.Presenter presenter;

    @Mock
    private Song song;
    private List<Song> songList;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        songList=new ArrayList<>(1);
        songList.add(song);
        songAdapterPresenter=new SortedSongSelectionPresenter.SongAdapterPresenter(adapter,presenter);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetItemCount(){

        songAdapterPresenter.getItemCount();
        verify(songList.size()).equals(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testonBindView(){

    }


}
```

When i run the testGetItemCount method i get `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException:`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The `verify` method of Mockito is used to interact with a mock, and make sure it was used as intended. For example, you could write `verify(song).something()` to make sure that the `something` method was called on the `song` mock.

In your case it looks like you are just looking for a way to verify (assert) the returned value. As this has nothing to do with your `song` mock, you should use a framework like Hamcrest with its `assertThat` method:

```
@Test
public void testGetItemCount() {
    int count = songAdapterPresenter.getItemCount();
    assertThat(count, is(1));
}
```

You can write assertions in any way you feel comfortable. As you're not interacting with a mock (`song` in your case), this is not the place to use Mockito.

Comment: I don't want to use Hamcrest.  Can you explain me the answer with Mockito

Comment: I already told you not to use Mockito. Don't use a knife if you need a hammer.

Comment: agree Mockito is not the right tool, you can use something simple like junit for simple assert